# Help in this exercise in Fulton's algebraic curves book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve the exercise 8.37 (page 111) in [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ewfulton/CurveBook.pdf):

[image]

I've already solved almost every item, it miss just the equivalence:

> The curve $X$ has a hyperelliptic Weierstrass point $\Leftrightarrow$
> there is a morphism $f:X\to \mathbb P^1$ of degree $2$.

I really need help.

Thanks

Comment: hello!! I'm having a hard time doing this exercise .. could you share your solution with me?

Answer (score 1):

If the curve has a hyperelliptic Weierstrass point $P$ then the number 2 is not a gap at $P$. Then by definition there is a $z$ with a pole of order $2$ at $P$.
The function $z$ can be regarded as a morphism $z: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree 2.  Conversely if there is such morphism $z: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree 2 then must be a ramification point $P$ somewhere in $X$ (this follows e.g. from Riemann-Hurwitz formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula ) (but also follows from the observation that a covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$ must be disconnected i.e. reducible). So at such $P$ the number 2 is not a gap at $P$.

Comment: Why $z$ can be regarded as a morphism $z:X\to \mathbb P^1$ of degree $2$? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: First of all any $z \in k(X)$ can be regarded as a morphism $\tilde{z}: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$. To see this just introduce homogeneous coordiantes $[u:v]$ in $\mathbb{P}^1$ and set $\tilde{z}(p) = [z(p) : 1]$ . If $z$ has a pole in $P$ then $\frac{1}{z(p)}$ has a zero at $P$ hence  $\tilde{z}(p) = [1: \frac{1}{z(p)}]$ is still defined at the pole of $z$. So $\tilde{z}$ is the morphism you get from the rational function $z$. You can check that the order of the pole of $z$ at $P$ is the cardinal (counting with multiplicities) of the preimage of the point $[1:0]$ hence the degree of $\tilde{z}$ .